# SwiftUI Map Camera Movement

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to have the map camera continuously animate around the globe.  Currently I'm trying to change the coordinateRegions latitude in the onAppear when the map loads.  Im using a timer to update the latitude every second.  So far i'm getting the error "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior; however the updated latitude is printing in the console but the map's coordinateRegion is not being updated."  I was wondering if there's a better way to continuously animate the map around the globe, in swiftUI.

Appreciate any help,
Thanks

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {

var timer = Timer()
@State var startlocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.851, -87.6238)
@State var endLatitude = 41.91 //North Avenue Beach

@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
    center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.851, longitude: -87.6238),
    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 40, longitudeDelta: 40)
)

func moveRegion() {
    var currentLatitude = region.center.latitude
           let increment = 0.00005
           Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: (1.0/30.0), repeats: true) { (timer) in
               currentLatitude += increment
               if currentLatitude >= self.endLatitude {
                   timer.invalidate()
               }
            region.center.latitude = currentLatitude
            print(currentLatitude)
           }
}

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: sites) { location in
        MapAnnotation(
            coordinate: location.coordinate,
            anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        ) {
            VStack {
                Circle()
                    .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(location.color.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 3))
                    .foregroundColor(location.color.opacity(0.5))
                    .frame(width: location.radius, height: location.radius)
            }
            
            }
    }.onAppear {
        moveRegion()
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/SvenTiigi/FlyoverKit I’ve integrated it into a SwiftUI project with a UIViewRepresentable. Might be of use to you.

Comment: i have not worked much with the new Map, but try putting everything that Xcode is saying that is causing undefined behaviour, into a `DispatchQueue.main.async {   }` and the error should go away.